# Publicly accessible Screen on Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to build a screen or page on acumatica that would be publicly accessible without login credentials.

The goal is to use this screen to allow any body to navigate to this page, get value from Acumatica database (It would be best if we could use BQL) then allow user to add more information in Non-Persistent DAC and call third party API to perform custom business logic.

Has anybody come up with such requirement and found any workaround to this?

It would be awesome if any workaround to this issue can be shared.

Cheers. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a separate controller and register it with Autofac.

Comment: Apology for the late response, but I guess when you meant separate controller it only applies to an MVC application built using Acumatica Framework and this doesn't apply to Acumatica ERP instance that uses WebForm. Did I get this right?

Comment: Check this https://www.acumatica.com/blog/using-asp-net-web-api-mvc-with-acumatica/